# How to launch electron app from a node.js script on mac?

Tags: macos, electron, electron-builder

I have a simple electron app I want to run on multiple platforms.  I launch the app from a git hook.  I have multiple platform specific packages of the app published to npm.  The windows path is working great.  Here is my windows commit-msg hook script (which runs my electron apps .exe, works great):

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var child_process = require('child_process');
const cFile = process.argv[2];

child_process.exec(`"C:\\users\\myuser\\nodejs\\node_modules\\azure-devops-work-items-win\\dist\\win\\azure-devops-work-items.exe" --repoPath=C:\\\\project\\.git\\hooks --commitFile=${cFile}`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error !== null) {
        console.log(error);
        process.exit(1);
    }
});
```

On mac I install this git hook script (which doesn't work).

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var child_process = require('child_process');
const cFile = process.argv[2];

child_process.exec(`"/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-devops-work-items-mac/dist/mac/azure-devops-work-items.app" --repoPath=/Users/meeusen/appdev/.git/hooks --commitFile=${cFile}`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error !== null) {
        console.log(error);
        process.exit(1);
    }
});
```

When the mac hook runs it errors with this message:

```
MeeusenMacBookPro:appdev meeusen$ git commit . -m"."
Error: Command failed: "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-devops-work-items-mac/dist/mac/azure-devops-work-items.app" --repoPath=/Users/meeusen/appdev/.git/hooks --commitFile=.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG
/bin/sh: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-devops-work-items-mac/dist/mac/azure-devops-work-items.app: is a directory

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:303:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:443:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:674:12) {
  killed: false,
  code: 126,
  signal: null,
  cmd: '"/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-devops-work-items-mac/dist/mac/azure-devops-work-items.app" --repoPath=/Users/meeusen/appdev/.git/hooks --commitFile=.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG'
}
```

It looks like I might be trying to launch this electron app wrong on the mac.  I'm a windows guy and am not sure if I'm going about this the right way.  What I want is to bundle my app with electron and then launch the platform specific binary via a nodejs script.  Should I be trying to launch the .app file?  Is there a better file that I should be trying to launch on mac?

I'm packaging my electron app with `electron-builder -mwl`.

My repo is [here](https://github.com/ChrisMeeusen/azure-devops-work-items)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the command line you can start `*.app` with `open` Like:

`open /usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-devops-work-items-mac/dist/mac/azure-devops-work-items.app`

if you want to use command line switches, you can add an `--args <actual arguments>` but it wont print anything in the cli. Since your script might rely on that, then there is a file inside .app than can be run and it will behave more like a unix command. Most likely in your script it will look like:

`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-devops-work-items-mac/dist/mac/azure-devops-work-items.app/Contents/MacOS/azure-devops-work-items" --repoPath=/Users/meeusen/appdev/.git/hooks --commitFile=${cFile}`